# showing messages in a label instead of the textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a program that gets the system information on my computer and i want it to compare the information system on another computer,if the parameters are the same then i write a message "matched" and if they are not i inconsistencies,my program worked nicely when i used textbox's like this below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.OperatingSystem OS = System.Environment.OSVersion;
            GetSystemInfo(ref n);

            string processor;
            switch (n.processorArchitecture)
            {
                case 0: processor = "Intel(x84)";
                    break;
                case 9: processor = "AMD or Intel (x64)";
                    break;
                default: processor = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            textBox10.Text = processor;
            textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(n.pageSize);
            textBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(n.minimumApplicationAddress);
            textBox13.Text = Convert.ToString(n.maximumApplicationAddress);
            textBox14.Text = Convert.ToString(n.activeProcessorMask);
            textBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(n.numberOfProcessors);
            textBox16.Text = Convert.ToString(n.processorType);
            textBox17.Text = Convert.ToString(n.processorLevel);
            textBox18.Text = Convert.ToString(n.processorRevision);

            int k = 13; 

            for (int i = 9, j = 10; i > 0 && j < 19; i--, j++)
            {
                if (this.Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()].Text == this.Controls["textBox" + j.ToString()].Text)
                    {

                        this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Visible = true;
                        this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Text = "VS";
                        this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Visible = true;
                        this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Text = "X";
                        this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }


                k++;
            }

            Check();




        }

        private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox8.Text == textBox11.Text)
            {
                label14.Text = "VS";
                label14.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                label14.Text = "X";
                label14.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            Check();
        }
```

this is my check function

```
 public void Check()
        {
            if (label13.Text == "VS" && label14.Text == "VS" && label15.Text == "VS" && label16.Text == "VS" && label17.Text == "VS" && label18.Text == "VS" && label19.Text == "VS" && label20.Text == "VS" && label21.Text == "VS")
            {
                label3.Text = "matches";
                label3.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                label3.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {

                label3.Text = "inconsistencies";
                label3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label3.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

wthe above code works perfectly but im just a newbie so i sort of want to try using just labels and i changed my code to this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.OperatingSystem OS = System.Environment.OSVersion;
            GetSystemInfo(ref n);

            string processor;
            switch (n.processorArchitecture)
            {
                case 0: processor = "Intel(x84)";
                    break;
                case 9: processor = "AMD or Intel (x64)";
                    break;
                default: processor = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            label10.Text = processor;
            label11.Text = Convert.ToString(n.pageSize);
            label12.Text = Convert.ToString(n.minimumApplicationAddress);
            label13.Text = Convert.ToString(n.maximumApplicationAddress);
            label14.Text = Convert.ToString(n.activeProcessorMask);
            label15.Text = Convert.ToString(n.numberOfProcessors);
            label16.Text = Convert.ToString(n.processorType);
            label17.Text = Convert.ToString(n.processorLevel);
            label27.Text = Convert.ToString(n.processorRevision);

            int k = 13;

            for (int i = 9, j = 10; i > 0 && j < 19; i--, j++)
            {
                if (this.Controls["label" + i.ToString()].Text == this.Controls["label" + j.ToString()].Text)
                {

                    this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Visible = true;
                    this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Text = "VS";
                    this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Visible = true;
                    this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].Text = "X";
                    this.Controls["label" + k.ToString()].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }


                k++;
            }

            Check();

        }

private void label11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label11.Text == label29.Text)
            {
                label19.Text = "VS";
                label19.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                label19.Text = "X";
                label19.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            Check();
        }
```

this is runing but the results are not true and the parameters from the computer are not being shown on the form?thanks in advance

Comment: You still need to use textboxes for the input fields. Label values can not be changed by the user by writing to it as a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the following function:

```
private void label11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

is not bound to `Label` with id `label11`.

To make sure it is bound, write following code in `Load` event of your form:

```
label11.OnTextChanged +=label11_TextChanged;
```